# Show only every 4th item from api data in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

From the API I'm getting an array of 40 objects. I want to show only 5 items. So my idea is to show only every 4th item, and skip the others. My idea is that I will filter the array first and if the condition is met, it will return the data, maybe using `map`?

```
const Weather = () => {

  const [key, setKey] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    city: "",
    country: ""
  })

  const API = '28876c50c36221de5f008fa752cb3f1a';

  const dataWeather = async () => {
    await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${data.city},${data.city}&appid=${API}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        // const {resData} = res.list;
        const { list: resData } = res.data
        console.log(resData);
        setKey(resData);
      })
  }

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setData(prev => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [name]: value
      }
    })
  }

  const trigger = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataWeather()
  }
  return (
    <Form>
      <Container>
        <Form>
          <Form.Row>
            <Col>
              <Form.Control placeholder="City" onChange={handleClick} name="city" value={data.city} />
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Form.Control placeholder="Country" onChange={handleClick} name="country" value={data.country} />
            </Col>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={trigger}>
              Submit
      </Button>
          </Form.Row>
        </Form>


        <div className="grid">
          {
            key !== null && (
              key.map(dataMap => 
              if (dataMap.dt_txt % 4 === 0) {
                <Card data={dataMap.weather[0].description} date={dataMap.dt_txt} imgSrc={dataMap.weather[0].icon} temp={Math.floor(dataMap.main.temp - 273.15)} />

              }
              )
            )

          }
        </div>

      </Container>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

Comment: i think you should share the working code, coz this doesnt look like it works.

Comment: Oh sorry i only post the specific one

Answer (score 1):

Use the `%` remainder operator to keep every Nth item, and skip the others.

```
list.filter((item, index) => index % 4 === 0)
```

Comment: This is a fine filter example, but to make it a complete answer please explain it for the OP as well as how it would be implemented in their specific case.

Comment: He asks about how to skip 4 out of 5 items from a list, does this not achieve that?

Comment: Should i still use a map to return a component if the filter condition idea is met?

Comment: `filter` removes items from a list, but preserves the structure of the items. You have to use `map` when you want transform the form of the items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will always return an array of the same length that it is called on, so removing elements is not possible without mutating it directly which is not the appropriate use of the method.

That being said, [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored) will accept children with values of `false` , `null`, `undefined`, and `true` but won't render them. So instead of explicitly filtering you can simply return `null` for elements you don't want to render.

```
key &&
key.map((dataMap, index) => {
  if (index % 4 === 0) {
    return <Card data={dataMap.weather[0].description} date={dataMap.dt_txt} imgSrc={dataMap.weather[0].icon} temp={Math.floor(dataMap.main.temp - 273.15)} />
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can apply a filter call before mapping. [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array of elements that return `true` for the passed condition. You can then chain your `map()` call on returned array.

```
key &&
  key
    .filter((_, index) => index % 4 === 0)
    .map(dataMap => (
      <Card data={dataMap.weather[0].description} date={dataMap.dt_txt} imgSrc={dataMap.weather[0].icon} temp={Math.floor(dataMap.main.temp - 273.15)} />
    )
```